# EJS isn't working(server brings up a listing directory page)

Tags: ejs

My problem is that I couldn't get express ejs working even a very basic and simple project.Express and ejs installed,I see them in the dependencies a node_modules.When I run the project I get a listing directory page but if I replace .ejs with .html it works.Here is the my code and settings;
app.js;

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index')
})
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening at port ${port}`)
})
```

index.ejs(inside the views folder);

## Hello World, there!

I've been struggling with this issue for two days.Any help will be appreciated very much.Thanx in advance.

I tried to uninnstall ejs and install it with -g option but it makes no difference.

Comment: What is your folder structure like? Do you have an `index.ejs` file in your views directory?

Comment: Yes I have.Index,ejs(index.ejs)is inside the views folder.

Comment: Sorry!In fact my index.ejs file's content is;                      
 <h1>Hello World, there!</h1>